# Copy all files from a list of folder locations

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, vbscript

I have a list of folder locations from which I would like to copy all the contained files at these locations. The list of folder locations are stored on a seperate line within a text file (.txt). All the files should be copied to the same location.

How can I complete this exercise using this list of folders in combination with a copy function at the command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken Elvins code and developed it slightly to solve the issue of spaces being included in folder paths and names.

The For Do command now uses a CSV file to source the folder paths from, it was then necessary to include the `"delims=,"` option within the For command.

```
for /f "delims=," %a in (D:\Batch_Files\Test_Bench\Folders_List.csv) do copy "%a\*" D:\Batch_Files\Test_Bench\Paste_All_The_Files_Here
```

The comma delimited records enabled the `For /f` to access the locations containing spaces but only if the token `%a\*` is wrapped in " ".

Answer (score 2):

Considering a file with a similar contents containing a list of directories such as:

```
c:
c:\users 
c:\anyotherfolder
```

`xcopy` inside a `for` loop will do the job :)

```
for /f %a in (list.txt) do xcopy /e %a\* c:\destination_folder\
```

(by copying the whole directory tree (owing to `/e`) )

---

You should add an extra `%` to the variable name if you want to keep and execute it on a separate `.bat` file.

Comment: Do the folder locations in list.txt need to separated with blank rows?

Comment: The way @Elvin responded, each folder should be on a separate line in the text file, but no extra blanks.  If you need to modify this, check out the `for /?` help command where it mentions delims and tokens.

Comment: No, it's not required (I reformatted my post for avoiding the confusion).

Comment: The script works perfectly when there are no spaces in the folder names. Can the code be modified for it to work when folder paths include spaces?

Comment: @BobJim yes, just use double quotes in the variable value - "%a"

Comment: The script still doesn't work, "in was unexpected at this time". I ran the following script: 'for /f "%a" in (D:\Batch_Files\Test_Bench\Folders_List.txt) do xcopy /e "%a"\* D:\Batch_Files\Test_Bench\Paste_All_The_Files_Here'

Comment: Un-quote the first variable.

Comment: I have unquoted the first variable (%a) - for /f %a in (D:\Batch_Files\Test_Bench\Folders_List.txt) do xcopy /e "%a\*" D:\Batch_Files\Test_Bench\Paste_All_The_Files_Here. The files within folder paths with no spaces copy fine, where a space occurs in the folder path the cmd prompt returns; File not found - *, 0 file(s) copied?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23731/discussion-between-bobjim-and-elvin-aslanov).